# Wait for ajax call in another js file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have two js files. These are the simplified version (there is a lot of code actually)

> ucyg.js

This file is included in a page `ucyg.php`  - this page is loaded into my `index.php` with an Ajax call.
its code is

```
var Ucyg = function(){

    var load = function() {
    return $.get('Ajax/listado_ucyg.php', {
                   // some get parameters
        }).done(function(data) {
            // some DOM manipulation with Data 
        });
    };

     return {
        load: load
     }
};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ucyg = new Ucyg(); 
        ucyg.load();
    });
```

So my ajax call return `ucyg.php` with this file included (to clarify: the file ucyg.js is not loaded in my browser until the ajax call of `ucyg.php` in my `index.php` returns), and when its ready, it does another ajax call to bring `listado_ucyg.php`

the other one

> item.js

in some part of the code I need something very similar to what I have in ucyg.php, but with some modifications. So I thought in bring `ucyg.php` as ajax call, and after that, make the  modifications needed. Just like this:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'Ajax/ucyg.php',
                success: function(data){
                    popUpUcyg(data, fila);
                },
                error: handleError
            });

    var popUpUcyg = function(data, fila){
     var a = $('#someid');
     a.html(data);
    // some dom manipulations (*)
}
```

the problem is that some of the DOM manipulations I should do is in the html code that the inner ajax call (`listado_ucyg.php`) returns.

So when I do `a.html(data)`, the data is rendered, the .js run its ready section and make  the ajax call for `listado_ucyg.php`, but I have to wait until it returns, in order to make the lasts modifications I need

How can I wait until this last ajax call is done? If its posible, I would like not to modify `ucyg.js`

I know I could put a timeout, but also I would like to avoid this.

In the server side I'm using PHP 5.3, in case anyone think in a option like passing a parameter to the server and do some magic

**EDIT:**

to clarify the sequence:

From index.php I can load any page with an ajax call - i.e. ucyg.php
File ucyg.php has `<script src="../Js/ucyg.js"></script>`
This `ucyg.js` got the code that you can see above.

In some point, from index.php I load item.php, and this page has `<script src="../Js/tareas.js"></script>`. 
In some point, this page (After a click event) needs to load something very similar to what I have in `ucyg.php`, you can see the code above. Instead of make another page, I chose to bring `ucyg.php` with an Ajax call, and make some modifications with js. The problem is that  when I bring ucyg.php, it includes the file ucyg.js (as we said), and this file, when its ready, make another ajax call.

Some of the modifitations I need to do, is in the data that this last ajax call does. So I need in someway to wait until this last one returns.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought of using jQuery's [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: I think that would involve change my ucyg.js file, and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do it, so that's why I would like to avoid it

Comment: Having hard time understanding sequence currently...what triggers call in items.js? Is it wrapped in a function call also? Promises is what you need , it's just that not clear best approach if can't touch the actual call of `ucyg.load();`

Comment: I will edit to clarify

Comment: @Gonzalo.- You don't have to edit `ucyg.js` file for using `promise`. You just need `jqXHR` returned by `ucyg.load();` to use `promise` API.

Comment: but how can I access the promise that ucyg.load() returns from the other file? is not a globar variable (right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to use `ajaxComplete()`

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if ( settings.url === "Ajax/listado_ucyg.php" ) {
        /* run DOM code from items.js*/
    }
});
```

[API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Could also use this to resolve promises that connect to the ajax calls in item.js